# Get Human readable time from nanoseconds

Tags: java, android, time, duration, datetime-conversion

I am trying to implement an ETA feature Using `System.nanoTime()`

```
startTime = System.nanoTime()
Long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
Long allTimeForDownloading = (elapsedTime * allBytes / downloadedBytes);

Long remainingTime = allTimeForDownloading - elapsedTime;
```

But I cannot figure how to get a human readable form of the nanoseconds; for example: `1d 1h`, `36s` and `3m 50s`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Would you mind using a lib for that? PrettyTime would be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `remainingTime` is in **nanoseconds**, just do the math and append the values to a `StringBuilder`:

```
long remainingTime = 5023023402000L;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
long seconds = remainingTime / 1000000000;
long days = seconds / (3600 * 24);
append(sb, days, "d");
seconds -= (days * 3600 * 24);
long hours = seconds / 3600;
append(sb, hours, "h");
seconds -= (hours * 3600);
long minutes = seconds / 60;
append(sb, minutes, "m");
seconds -= (minutes * 60);
append(sb, seconds, "s");
long nanos = remainingTime % 1000000000;
append(sb, nanos, "ns");

System.out.println(sb.toString());

// auxiliary method
public void append(StringBuilder sb, long value, String text) {
    if (value > 0) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(value).append(text);
    }
}
```

The output for the above is:

> 1h 23m 43s 23402000ns

(1 hour, 23 minutes, 43 seconds and 23402000 nanoseconds).

Answer (score 12):

I would say both of these answers are correct, but anyways here is a little shorter version of a function that accepts nano time and returns human-readable String.

```
private String getReadableTime(Long nanos){

    long tempSec    = nanos/(1000*1000*1000);
    long sec        = tempSec % 60;
    long min        = (tempSec /60) % 60;
    long hour       = (tempSec /(60*60)) % 24;
    long day        = (tempSec / (24*60*60)) % 24;
    
    return String.format("%dd %dh %dm %ds", day,hour,min,sec);

}
```

For maximum accuracy, instead of integer division, you can use float division and round up.

Answer (score 4):

### *java.time*

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long elapsedTime = 12345678987654321L;

        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos(elapsedTime);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format(
                "%02d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond", duration.toDays(),
                duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                duration.toMillis() % 1000, duration.toNanos() % 1000000L);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toMillisPart(), duration.toNanosPart() % 1000000L);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT3429H21M18.987654321S
142 Day 21 Hour 21 Minute 18 Second 987 Millisecond 654321 Nanosecond
142 Day 21 Hour 21 Minute 18 Second 987 Millisecond 654321 Nanosecond
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I really like this solution, but I don't think it handles the ms/ns split correctly.  E.g. if I feed it a value of `7,139,410` nanoseconds, it will spit back out `7 Millisecond 7139410 Nanosecond`.  I.e. it didn't take the 7ms off of the 7.1 million nanoseconds, effectively reporting that twice.  I think you can see it in your example output as well (`987ms 987654321ns`)

Comment: I used `duration.toNanosPart() % 1000000l` for the nanosecond part for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

It is my old code, you can convert it to days also.

```
  private String calculateDifference(long timeInMillis) {
    String hr = "";
    String mn = "";
    long seconds = (int) ((timeInMillis) % 60);
    long minutes = (int) ((timeInMillis / (60)) % 60);
    long hours = (int) ((timeInMillis / (60 * 60)) % 24);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hr = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        mn = "0" + minutes;
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><small;text-align: justify;><font color=\"#000\">" + "Total shift time: " + "</font></small; text-align: justify;></i>" + "<font color=\"#47a842\">" + hr + "h " + mn + "m " + seconds + "s" + "</font>"));
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion. It's based on the fact that the units in `TimeUnit.values()` are sorted from smallest (nanoseconds) to longest (days).

```
    private static String getHumanReadableTime(long nanos) {
        TimeUnit unitToPrint = null;
        String result = "";
        long rest = nanos;
        for(TimeUnit t: TimeUnit.values()) {
            if (unitToPrint == null) {
                unitToPrint = t;
                continue;
            }
            // convert 1 of "t" to "unitToPrint", to get the conversion factor
            long factor = unitToPrint.convert(1, t);
            long value = rest % factor;
            rest /= factor;

            result = value + " " + unitToPrint + " " + result;

            unitToPrint = t;
            if (rest == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rest != 0) {
            result = rest + " " + unitToPrint + " " + result;
        }

        return result.trim();
    }
```

Output for `getHumanReadableTime(139543185092L)` will be

```
2 MINUTES 19 SECONDS 543 MILLISECONDS 185 MICROSECONDS 92 NANOSECONDS
```