# How to display the date in the right format after stopWatch?

Tags: java, guava

I’m recently working with guava. Stopwatch has such a question.
I have a method that calculates the total time the put method is executed and the quantity, in order to calculate the average time spent on the execution of the put method.

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        cacheEntry.put(str, new CacheEntry(str));
        putCounter++;
        mapBasedStatisticsCache.setPutCounter(putCounter);
        currentTime += stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        System.out.println(currentTime);
        mapBasedStatisticsCache.setCurrentTime(currentTime);
```

After that, I calculate the average time in nanoseconds

```
public long getAveragePutTime() {
        return getCurrentTime() / getPutCounter();
    }
```

How can I then parse the result of the getAveragePutTime method to the hh: mm: ss: ms format?

I'm trying to do this way:

```
public String getAveragePutTime() {
    long result = getCurrentTime() / getPutCounter();
    long hh = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toHours(result);
    long mm = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMinutes(result);
    long ss = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(result);
    long ms = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(result);
    return "Hours: " + hh + " minutes: " + mm + " seconds: " + ss + " millisecond: " + ms;
}
```

But I have this result:

```
Nanos: 128240
Hours: 0 minutes: 0 seconds: 0 millisecond: 0
```

Comment: calculate the different values?

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061338/get-human-readable-time-from-nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

You have 128420 nanoseconds. That's 0.000128420 seconds. That's 0.128420 milliseconds. 0.128420 milliseconds in integers is 0 milliseconds. So your result is actually normal.

However... You have other issues! Your `getAveragePutTime()` is written in a way that you will have redundant numbers. So when you have hours, remove them from the leftovers:

```
public String getAveragePutTime() {
  long result = getCurrentTime() / getPutCounter();
  long hh = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toHours(result);
  result -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos(hh);
  long mm = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMinutes(result);
  result -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(mm);
  long ss = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(result);
  result -= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(mm);
  long ms = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(result);
  return "Hours: " + hh + " minutes: " + mm + " seconds: " + ss + " millisecond: " + ms;
}
```